# Acadamic Search API returns no entity

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have problem in accessing microsoft academic research API. It returns no entity when I tried to query by id

this is my request:

```
    GET https://api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com/academic/v1.0/evaluate? 
    expr=Id=2134295053&model=latest&count=1&offset=0&attributes=Id,Ti,RId 
    HTTP/1.1
    Host: api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com
    Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: ••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••••
```

the expected result is that it will return paper attributes(id, title, and reference Id)

but this is the response that I got from the API:

```
   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
   Request-Context: appId=cid-v1:7cd06f0e-6d73-46a5-9c10-4ebe681d0156
   Date: Thu, 03 Jan 2019 15:11:34 GMT
   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
   Content-Length: 63
   Content-Type: application/json

   {
      "expr": "Id=2134295053",
      "entities": [{
        "logprob": -15.913
      }]
    }
```

Is there problem with the academic search API right now?

Answer (score 0):

Stange result on your side, it is working on mine with the same parameters, see below:

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this problem for the past month where I check that the API calls for Id is working before I start coding, and then after a few minutes of development work, the API stops returning data.

At 10:36 today I sent a call and got this back:
    {
    "expr":"And(Id=2890264470)",
    "entities":
    [
    {"logprob":-23.472,"Id":2890264470,"CC":0}]
    }

After a half hour of work, I am not getting zero results back (no "CC" value):

```
{
"expr":"And(Id=2890264470)",
"entities":
[
{"logprob":-23.472}]
}
```